# Chances of winning a particular carnival game

Tags: probability

Here are the rules of the carnival game, in the simplest terms I can make them:

There is a table with 12 spaces on it numbered 1 through 12. The game operator puts 6 black tokens on spaces 1-3 and 10-12, while the player puts 6 white tokens on spaces 4-9. The operator and player take turns rolling 2 dice (starting with the operator) and try to roll a number (the sum of the 2 dice) that has an opposing token on it. They roll 10 times each or until all of the spaces belong to either the operator or the player. Whoever has more spaces as theirs in the end wins (ties go to the operator). If the player rolls a number on their own space, they do not lose it.

The game is obviously unfair, as you can see from [this chart](http://www.chrisbeales.net/env_images/env_dice%20results%20table.jpg)  (the operator has a 3/4 chance of landing on the player's space on their first roll and the player can never take the "1" space). My question is how probable would it be to win this game? Am I overthinking it and would it just be 1/4? Or is it more complicated than that? How would you calculate the probability of winning?

Comment: I think $\frac{27}{36}=\frac34$ not $\frac23$. And it seems unlikely that $1$ will be ever rolled as the sum of two dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Binomial probability distribution:

Probability of operator winning = $^{10}C_6\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^4 = 0.2276$

Probability of player winning = $^{10}C_6\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^6 = 0.0569$

Comment: why $^{10}C_6$ ?

Comment: because we need 6 wins out of 10 trials

Comment: Thank you! I realize that I had some calculations wrong before (they're fixed now) so this answer is technically wrong but it put me on the right track and I'll be able to figure it out myself.